# When should I call header('Location') without die()?

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers, location, die

Does calling `header('Location:')` without `die()` after it make sense at all?

If not, why isn't `die()` being performed automatically by PHP interpreter? If yes, when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good example is explained in [this PHP user note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#89177), copied here for posterity:

---

> A simple but useful packaging of arr1's suggestion for continuing
>   processing after telling the the browser that output is finished.
>
> I always redirect when a request requires some processing (so we don't
>   do it twice on refresh) which makes things easy...

```
<?php 
 function redirect_and_continue($sURL) 
 { 
  header( "Location: ".$sURL ) ; 
  ob_end_clean(); //arr1s code 
  header("Connection: close"); 
  ignore_user_abort(); 
  ob_start(); 
  header("Content-Length: 0"); 
  ob_end_flush(); 
  flush(); // end arr1s code 
  session_write_close(); // as pointed out by Anonymous 
 } 
?>
```

---

This is useful for tasks that take a long time, such as converting a video or scaling a big image.

Comment: Will implement my own redirect() the same way.

Comment: @noober: Ok, just remember that most of the time, *it makes sense to `die()` after `Location`*! Also, I believe `session_write_close()` should come before the `Location` header and not at the end.

Answer (score 4):

`header('Location: ')` will make [HTTP redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_redirect) that tells the browser to go to the new location:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://example.com/another_page.php
Connection: close
```

It doesn't need any HTML body since the browser won't display it and just follow the redirection. That's why we call `die()` or `exit()` after `header('Location:')`. If you don't terminate the script, the HTTP response looks like this.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://example.com/another_page.php
Connection: close

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>This is a useless page, won't displayed by the browser</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Why do I have to make SQL queries and other stuff 
       if the browser will discard this? -->
</body>
</html>
```

**why isn't die() being performed automatically by PHP interpreter?**

The `header()` function is used to send raw HTTP header, not limited to `header('Location:')`. For example:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
// ...more code...
```

In those situation we don't call `die()` since we need to generate HTTP response body. So it doesn't make sense if PHP automatically call `die()` after `header()`.

Answer (score 3):

In my personal opinion you should call `die()` at the point you don't want the script to be executed any more. If you don't want the script to be executed after your `header("Location: ...")` you should put `die()` right after it.

Basically if you don't do it, your script might do needless extra calculations, that never will be "visible" to the user since the server redirects him anyway.

Comment: OK, then when do you want the script to be executed after header('Location:')? Any example?

Comment: There are situations you might want to do some extra calculations, store some things, clean up some resources, you  name it. There are plenty of use cases, but it is all situation based. If you don't need to do anything after the `header("Location:...")` you won't need to worry about it and just put `die` after it.